# How to pass custom nativescript-Vue component to custom child Component

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I would like to add a dynamic child component to a parent component using Nativescript-Vue. For example:

```
<template>
    <MyParentComponent>
        <MyChildComponent :foo="foo"></MyChildComponent>
    </MyParentComponent>
<template>

<script>
    import MyParentComponent from './components/MyParentComponent';
    import MyChildComponent from './components/MyChildComponent';

    export default {
        components: {
            MyParentComponent,
            MyChildComponent
        },
        data: function(){
            return {
                foo: ''
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I think I need to define a slot in the parent component where the child component should be inserted, but I don't know how this should be done.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `MyParentComponent`'s template you need to add a `<slot />` tag, that's where Vue will insert the content.

Read more about slots, and what they can do in the Vue docs:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots

Comment: Fantastic. So it is exactly as it is in Vue.js. I don't know why my tests failed before, but now it works perfectly. Thanks!